Risk with censored covariates - which method should I use?
TL;DR - my data consists of:

Age of toddler visit to hospital due to household injury.
Record of age at which toddler crawls, walks and runs. Records are censored since some toddlers arrive at the hospital before they start (e.g.) walking.

I want to predict "risk of household injury". How should I proceed?
Now at more length: I have data for toddlers who visited a hospital due to a household injury. Each toddler visits a nurse in the community every once in a while, and said nurse takes note of whether the toddler can (A) crawl, (B) walk, (C) run. Progression is monotonous: a toddler that walks can surely crawl, and toddler that runs can does not stop running. I believe that toddler age and age at achieving mobility levels A,B and C above are indicators of risk of household injury, since a toddler that is more mobile can get hurt more often.
For a given toddler, I would like to calculate a risk measure for household injury. My thoughts:

Surely I cannot calculate the probability of injury $\Pr(injury)$ since I have no records of toddlers that did not visit the hospital.
I cannot just naively use logisitc regression for similar reasons.
Maybe calculate odds-ratio relative to some baseline age and use the rare disease approximation? But then how do I incorporate information on mobility levels A,B and C?
I don't think Cox regression is appropriate here since I am not really modeling time to event.

Please suggest methods to define and find the "risk of injury" for a toddler. I would also appreciate explanations on the approaches I mentioned.

"Each toddler visits a nurse in the community every once in a while, and said nurse takes note of whether the toddler can (A) crawl, (B) walk, (C) run." Is that also true of toddlers who don't have an injury and are seen for general well-being checkups or for reasons other than injury (fevers, ear infections, etc.)?

@EdM Yes. I might be able to get that data.

I suspect that the same toddler can have visits for multiple distinct injury incidents. If so, do you want to consider multiple injuries in the analysis or just limit to the first injury?

@EdM just the first. You'd hope the parents would be more careful after the first injury but surely that is not always the case lol

This isn't an ideal solution (I am not sure there is one, you might need different data) but if you have some estimate of the catchment area of the hospital, and the age distribution of the population, you could use that to estimate the denominator.
Population pyramids are certainly available at a country-wide level -- that may be far from perfect as different areas have different age distributions, but it's at least something. Hospital administration may have some estimate of catchment area.

Lets say I have data from all hospitals and that I can retrieve population pyramids from other sources. How would you proceed in this case?

Then you have a good estimate of the total number of children, and your problem bascailly disappears.

I dont quite follow: lets say my training dataset contains everything i want. I.e. age at each developmental stage, age at injury (if occured) and population size. I can find a model for risk of injury at each age, given that i know (future) develompmental stages. But for a real toddler my data is truncated / censored. How can i proceed to estimate risk?

Ummm .... Maybe I'm being dense, but you do it from the model.

I have a couple of thoughts that are too long for comments.
First, even if you are limited to data on toddlers who have been treated for injuries, you might still be able to evaluate how toddler age is associated with injury risk. What you then have is considered right truncated event times, which are often found in epidemiology studies. That is, the cases with data are only those who have already experienced the event, providing no information for those who haven't yet done so.
The trick, as explained in Section 5.3 of Klein and Moeschberger, is to reverse the time axis. Choose some fixed upper age limit for being a toddler and model the (positive) difference between that fixed upper age and the age at first injury. That converts the right truncation to left truncation, which can be handled (with some precautions) by the counting-process data format used to generate survival curves.
Second, it's not completely clear to me how to model the mobility stage (crawling/walking/running) separately from age. Including the most recent mobility stage as a predictor would seem to lead to survivorship bias (being able to walk without having had an injury means that you have already reached some age). Also, the probability of having an injury during the pre-running walking stage, for example, would depend on the duration of that stage (before running is achieved). It might be possible to use a multi-state model in a way that takes stage duration into account, particularly if you can get the "denominator" of at-risk individuals for your risk calculations from hospital or demographic records.

I dont quite follow: my dependent variable is not truncated - if there is an injury (e.g. by age 18, which is far beyond the toddler stage) i see it in my data. My covariates / independent variableare right truncated, though, and that is exactly my problem

@YairDaon right truncation has a specific technical meaning in survival analysis. Say that you are using age at injury as your event time, and put aside for now the issue of crawling/walking/running. Although you might know the age when an individual has an injury, that individual's age at injury provides no information about individuals who haven't yet had an injury (your problem 1). Those known ages at injury are "right truncated" in that technical sense. This can be an problem in epidemiological studies like yours, when you only have data on individuals who have experienced the event.
